# Update Panel and listing items

Tags: development

I have got a code, on procedure Button_Click:

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web)
                {


                    // Dodawanie poszczególnych dni projektowych
                    SPListItemCollection listItems = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].Items;
                    SPListItem item = listItems.Add();
                    item["Kontrakt"] = TextBox1.Text;
                    item["Pracownik"] = TextBox2.Text;
                    item["Dzien"] = TextBox3.Text;
                    var selectedGroup = DropDownList2.SelectedItem;
                    item["Procenty"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(int.Parse(selectedGroup.Value), selectedGroup.Text);

                    string DateOnlyQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>";
                  //  string FullQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Pracownik' /><Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
                    string dateISO = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox3.Text).ToLocalTime());

                    var query2 = new SPQuery();
                    query2.Query = String.Format(DateOnlyQuery, "Data", dateISO);
                    query2.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Data' />";
                    query2.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                    SPListItemCollection listaDniSwiatecznych = witryna.Lists["DR2013 Święta"].GetItems(query2);

                    foreach (SPListItem olistaDniSwiatecznych in listaDniSwiatecznych)
                    {
                        Label2.Text = olistaDniSwiatecznych["Kontrakt"].ToString();
                    }

                    // Zaktualizowanie wpisu w liscie projektów
                    item.Update();
                    this.TextBox1.Text = "";
                    this.TextBox2.Text = "";
                    this.TextBox3.Text = "";
                    Label2.Text = "Dodałeś nowy wpis";
                }
            }
```

If I try listing items on label in or not in Update Panel, I can't see anything. Any code doesn't listing on site. I don't see any writings. It's don't see label.
Here of declaration of update panel:

```
`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by erase a using method from this line:

SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;

And now it's works good.